# How to rebase and push correctly in git using terminal

Tags: git

I was using VS Code git plugin for a while and now my new project is using the terminals to do the Gits and kid of new to the terminal mode.

Here is what I did so far, please suggest...

1. git clone http://remoteurl
2. git branch : output name is showing a branch name like 'stagingonly' ( not showing a name like master, let it be that)
3. git checkout -b X  : to create branch X
4. I did all the codings in X
   : and now my team has alot new codes in the remote repo http://remoteurl , and adviced me to do rebase and push the code for code-review using terminal.

> > Please advice the missing step to do a rebase & remove conflicts and push the code ( remote repo is an azure devops repo)

Saw alot of steps in google, but thought of not messing with the client repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Checkout stagingonly and pull, to bring it up to date.
2. Now checkout X and rebase stagingonly, resolving any conflicts, and
   push.

That way, your branch X branches off the end of stagingonly
    and it will be easier and cleaner to merge it in the pull request.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for this, could you please type the command step by step.

Comment: I believe that is just what I did.

Answer (score 0):

you may just run `git pull --rebase origin stagingonly` to rebase all your commits onto latest state of remote version `stagingonly` branch. It will look like you just created your feature branch and put all you commits after latest ones from team branch.
For push `git push --force-with-lease`. `--force-with-lease` flag is needed, when commit's history on remote repo should be rewritten.

**Note**: local `stagingonly` branch will be behind `origin/stagingonly` link in your local repo. In order to update local `stagingonly` as well, you should run:

```
 1. git checkout stagingonly //switch onto local stagingonly 
 2. git pull --rebase //get latest changes and update local copy
 3. git checkout featureBranch //switch onto your local featurebranch
 4. git pull --rebase //it is necessary, if someone else is working in your branch.
 5. git rebase staging only //rebase local featurebranch onto local staginonly
 6. git push --force-with-lease //
```

Hope, you'll find it helpful.